# Texture corruption on Geforce GTX 770, textures have holes in them

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-geforce

This is my machine:

- Intel i5 2500k, 3.3 Ghz;
- Asus P8P67 Pro, Rev. 1.XX, stock BIOS;
- Geforce GTX 770, driver version 359.06;
- 8 GB RAM (not sure what model);
- 1 TB Samsung 850 Evo SSD, 1 TB WD HDD;
- Windows 10 Home with latest updates.

The issue that I have is best explained through an image:

[image]

As you can see, certain textures, both in games and on certain applications, appear as if they have been applied to a a grate, not a smooth surface. Closeup of the image to show the exact issue:

[image]

When this happens, I need to restart that program to fix them. I have noticed this issue in the Battle.net desktop client for Blizzard games and in Assassin's Creed: Syndicate (on the minimap and in the menus). They could be present in other programs, but those are the 2 I have noticed them in the most so far.

Steps I have tried:

1. rebooting the computer fixes it temporarily, but is not a permanent fix.
2. Restarting the program has the same result as rebooting my computer.
3. I have used Display Driver Uninstaller to completely uninstall my drivers, then install fresh ones from Geforce Experience, but with no difference;
4. Someone in the Superuser chatroom told me it might be related to my Logitech G510 and a bug in Windows 10 pre 1511 update that can crash my video drivers when using the volume controls. I installed the 1511 update, but while it fixed my Logitech issue, I still have the textures issue.

I have talked with the users in the Root Access chatroom about this. I have had some recommendations that updating my BIOS might help, but the most recent BIOS update on the Asus support page is from November 2012, while the Geforce GTX 770 is from May 2013, which is half a year later. I also have had the 770 for well over a year now and have only recently started to notice this issue. I suspect it might be an issue with Windows 10, but I'm not sure. Either way, I find it somehwat unlikely that a 3 year old BIOS update can fix an issue with a 2 year old GPU in an OS that's less than 1 year old.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

edit: GPU-Z specs of my GTX 770 in case they're relevant.

[image]

Comment: Any problems with the `GTX 770` are not connected to Windows 10.  I have a `GTX 770` so it is either a driver specific to your system or a hardware problem.  If it helps I very rarely have a problem with that Battle.net client myself so not related to Windows 10.  Its worth pointing out the two clients you are using, use your card in exactly the same way (Directx vs OpenGL), so its entirely possible its a bug in the Nvidia driver itself.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't have the issue when my computer was still on Windows 7 though. Whatever causes it is something that's common between both OSes.

Comment: All I know is I rarely have the issue with the Battle.net client (something like once a month), I highly suspect, its a Nvidia driver problem.  I have **never** seen it happen in any application, but I recognize the problem, so its likely the same issue.  I also had the problem before the Fall Update so its not a recent driver bug.  It also shows performing an update on your UEFI firmware would be sort of pointless, since we have different motherboards, thus eliminating that as the possible solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity what make is the graphics card and what version is the BIOS that people are recommending you update from and to? Any chance of an in-game screenshot of this happening?  There *are* later bios versions, with some as late as mid-2014 http://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/index.php?architecture=&manufacturer=MSI&model=GTX+770&interface=&memType=&memSize=

Comment: @Mokubai My GPU is made by Asus. The BIOS they're referring to is that of my motherboard. I will try to get an ingame screenshot, but it doesn't happen every time I start a game. Interesting comment about this being a memory brownout. Is this fixable without replacing parts? I haven't budgeted any major computer-related expenses for 2016, and was planning to get an entirely new PC in 2017, so I'd rather not replace parts in 2016.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Scratch my earlier comments, you'd probably have a lot more problems with graphics going very weird if it were a hardware fault on those lines.  Shader programs getting invalid model data and all that jazz.  What *is* curious though is that the errors appear to be specifically with items that have a transparency effect on them (but not all items) which suggests that the problem is something more curious and likely driver related.  I'm even more curious to see a game screenshot now. Could you run [GPU-z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) and log memory usage while playing?

Comment: Borrow another gpu..  This will at least rUle about the card

Comment: @Dave I got a 560 in my attic, but that would be a quite big downgrade for me, so even if it doesn't have the issue, I'd rather not be forced to go down that much.

Comment: @Mokubai So either this is a hardware issue, or it's a driver issue from what you guys say. Could continued usage of this card damage the card (further) in either case?

Comment: Rethinking the problem it is either something wrong with the texturing or rasterizing units or it is simply a strange driver fault not passing some very particular data to the card. The strangeness of it makes it very difficult to pinpoint where the error lies though.  Windows 10 did manage to screw up the drivers for my GTX770 during the upgrade, I had some weird graphics glitch on the login screen that persisted through a clean remove/reinstall of the drivers, but on a clean install of the OS (HDD was near death and it was due anyway) the glitch is gone. That is a bit extreme though...